# Python-Calculating the roots of a simple non-linear equation system

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sympy

**As title says, here is my system:**

```
[;Acos(\phi)=1;]

[;-0.5Asin(\phi)=0;]
```

**The obvious solutions are**

`A=1 and [;\phi=n\pi , n\in \mathbb{Z};],`

I tried using sympy..nsolve(doesn't work) and scipy..fsolve(gives an error "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats")

Comment: *'scipy..fsolve(gives an error "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats")'*  If you don't show us the actual code that you used, it is hard for anyone to help you with that.  Creating a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it much easier for someone to help you with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of trigonometric functions makes the system difficult to solve, even though it appears to be a "simple" one.

One approach to easily find the solutions of a system that includes terms of the form `cos(x)` and/or `sin(x)` is to perform the substitution `u=cos(x)`, `v=sin(x)`, introduce the additional equation `u**2 + v**2 == 1`, and solve for `u`, `v`. Variable `x` can then be obtained from the value(s) of `u`.

```
import sympy as sp

A, u, v, phi = sp.symbols('A, u, v, phi', real = True)

eqs = [sp.Eq(A * u, 1), sp.Eq(-A * v/2, 0), sp.Eq(u**2 + v**2, 1)]
sol = sp.solve(eqs, [A, u, v])
print (sol)
```

> `[(-1, -1, 0), (1, 1, 0)]`

It follows that `A` can take two values (`-1`, `1`). For `A=-1` it must hold `u==-1`, which corresponds to an infinite number of values of `phi` as follows

```
sp.solveset(sp.Eq(sp.cos(phi),-1), phi)
```

> `ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + pi), Integers())`

The procedure is similar for `A=1`.